# L2TP over IPSec strongswan/xl2tpd pppd interface name changes

Tags: vpn, point-to-point-protocol, xl2tpd

I have encountered a possible problem in my VPN setup. I have two different entry points into clients network, so I set two services up and, since one of the VPN-connections is slightly better for us, set it's metric to 100 and another to 101 like following.

`/etc/ppp/ip-up.local`

```
  metric=100
  if [[ $PPP_IFACE == 'ppp2' ]]; then
    metric=101;
    # ppp2 have lower priority
  fi;
  route add -net 10.20.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 dev $PPP_IFACE metric $metric
```

The interface names are set in `/etc/ppp/*.options` with `unit 2` and `unit 3`:

```
ipcp-accept-local
ipcp-accept-remote
refuse-eap
require-chap
noccp
noauth
#noaccomp
mtu 1280
mru 1280
noipdefault
#defaultroute
nodefaultroute
#usepeerdns
unit 2
connect-delay 5000
name myname
password mypassword
```

Since I *knew* the names of the interfaces, I was lazy and just added fix rules to `iptables` and thought I was done with it (instead of adding/removing them in a script).

But then I saw an `ppp0` interface...

Some research got me this.

`sudo grep -iRn "pppd" /var/log/` give me this

```
/var/log/syslog:5697:Jul 29 10:55:58 debian-router pppd[5153]: LCP terminated by peer
/var/log/syslog:5698:Jul 29 10:55:58 debian-router pppd[5153]: Connect time 643.1 minutes.
/var/log/syslog:5699:Jul 29 10:55:58 debian-router pppd[5153]: Sent 0 bytes, received 0 bytes.
/var/log/syslog:5702:Jul 29 10:55:58 debian-router pppd[5153]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1280
/var/log/syslog:5703:Jul 29 10:55:58 debian-router pppd[5153]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1280
/var/log/syslog:5707:Jul 29 10:55:58 debian-router xl2tpd[3016]: Terminating pppd: sending TERM signal to pid 5153
/var/log/syslog:5708:Jul 29 10:55:58 debian-router pppd[5153]: Terminating on signal 15
/var/log/syslog:5713:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router xl2tpd[3016]: start_pppd: I'm running:
/var/log/syslog:5714:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router xl2tpd[3016]: "/usr/sbin/pppd"
/var/log/syslog:5724:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: Plugin pppol2tp.so loaded.
/var/log/syslog:5725:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
/var/log/syslog:5726:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: Couldn't allocate PPP unit 2 as it is already in use
/var/log/syslog:5727:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: Using interface ppp0
/var/log/syslog:5728:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: Connect: ppp0 <-->
/var/log/syslog:5729:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1280
/var/log/syslog:5730:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: Overriding mru 1500 to mtu value 1280
/var/log/syslog:5732:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: Overriding mtu 1500 to 1280
/var/log/syslog:5733:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5613]: PAP authentication succeeded
/var/log/syslog:5734:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5153]: Connection terminated.
/var/log/syslog:5736:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5153]: Modem hangup
/var/log/syslog:5737:Jul 29 10:56:01 debian-router pppd[5153]: Exit.
```

So what happens must be... For some (probably irrelevant) reason the connection is terminated, upon which `xl2tpd` sends `TERM` to the `pppd[5153]` and then starts new `pppd[5613]` for the new connection. But `pppd[5153]` needs some time to exit and so `pppd[5613]` can't use designated interface name `ppp2`.

`/etc/xl2tpd/xl2tpd.conf` is like this.

```
[lac vpn1]
lns = 10.20.30.40
;ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.vpn1.l2tpd
length bit = yes
redial = yes
redial timeout = 2
; max redials = 15

[lac vpn2]
lns = 10.20.30.41
;ppp debug = yes
pppoptfile = /etc/ppp/options.vpn2.l2tpd
length bit = yes
redial = yes
redial timeout = 2
; max redials = 15
```

Now, I guess I could set `redial timeout` in `xl2tpd.conf` higher, but it wouldn't be very clean solution to the problem. So the question is, is it possible to ensure device name is kept across reconnects? (If not I guess I could just use `$PPP_REMOTE` -- but not really, since it's not the `lns = 10.20.30.41`! -- in my `ip-up.local` instead of `$PPP_IFACE` and add/remove `iptables` rules there too, but maybe there is a better way).

**Update**
I added `ipparam vpn1` and `ipparam vpn2` to the `/etc/ppp/*.options` files and use `$PPP_IPPARAM` to distinguish between the two; I guess this is the most stable solution.

Additional info:

- OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
- ipsec: Linux strongSwan U5.7.2/K4.19.0-9-amd64
- xl2tpd: xl2tpd-1.3.12